# Why does this function of two number sum return 'None' instead of returning [-1, 11]?

Tags: python, list, nonetype

```
def twosum(array, targetSum):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        firstNum = array[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
            secondNum = array[j]
            if firstNum + secondNum == targetSum:
                return sorted(firstNum, secondNum)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(twosum(['3', '5', '-4', '8', '11', '1', '-1', '6'], 10))
```

Comment: Probably because `return sorted(firstNum, secondNum)` is never encountered.

Comment: And if it were, it would be an error.

Comment: You are adding and comparing strings, not integers. That's the first issue...

Comment: Note that `'-1' + '11' = '-111'`, not `10`

Comment: This will be much simpler if you use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are treating strings like integers. However, much of the complexity of your function is already implemented in the standard library, in the form of `itertools.combinations`.

```
from itertools import combinations


def twoSum(array, target):
    for x, y in combinations(map(int, array), 2):
        if x + y == target:
            return [x, y] if x <= y else [y, x]  # sorted is overkill here
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the items in the `array` were `str` you can cast them to `int` and sort function takes iterable so you can add both of the numbers to a list.

```
def twosum(array, targetSum):
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        firstNum = array[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(array)):
            secondNum = array[j]
            #print(firstNum, secondNum, firstNum + secondNum)
            if firstNum + secondNum == targetSum:
                return sorted([firstNum, secondNum])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(twosum([int(i) for i in ['3', '5', '-4', '8', '11', '1', '-1', '6']], 10))
```

Output

```
[-1, 11]
```

Comment: It might make more sense to change the input to ints to begin with. I suspect that OP's homework assignment didn't stipulate inputs that consisted of a list of strings and an int. My guess is that the quote marks around the numbers in OP's function call is a mistake on their part.